# How to set permissions for bug reporters

Tags: azure-devops

I need to know if there is granular use access options within Azure DevOps. Is there a way to create a user to add new bug reports only. The user should only be able to see existing but reports and add new reports, not assign or modify them. This will be non IT person as super user level that could supply feedback only.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to create a user to add new bug reports only

Based on your requirement, you need to set the permission at work item level.

I am afraid that there is no such method could set the permission for work item level (e.g. Bug work item). Azure Devops sets permissions based on the node level(e.g. Area and Iteration)

You can try the following steps to restrict and manage the target users。

1. Create a child node for the target users in `Project Settings -> Project configuration -> Area`.
2. Set the `Edit work items in this node` permission for the `Child Area node -> Security`.

[image]

3. Set this user's permissions on other nodes to **Deny**

**Note:** In this case, the user can create any work item in this child node and edit it. We cannot restrict users to only create bug work items and cannot edit it.

If you want to restrict multiple users, you can create a group and set the permission.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I was not able make it work. I have just started to use DevOps and we just use it to record the bugs, requirements and features. We do not use it for source control just paperwork.

Comment: The answer is related with the permission about work items(bugs, features and so on). We couldn't control the permission for  single work item type for the time being. So as a workaround, you could try to set the permission for each area. This helps you manage work items